WinUI 3 NavigationView PaneDisplayMode Bottom
The NavigationView does not provide an option for bottom alignment. I only see: Auto, Left, Top, LeftCompact, LeftMinimal.
I could manage to place the NavigationView to the Bottom, but the problem now is that the          Header="This is Header Text" is also on the bottom and would need to be on the top of the actual NavigatioView.
Thanks in advance for some help
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Page
   x:Class="MyApp.Views.SelectorBarPage"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:local="using:MyApp.Views"
   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
   mc:Ignorable="d"
   Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
   
   
   
   <!-- DisplayMode top -->
   <StackPanel
       x:Name="TopNavArea"
       Background="Black"
       Grid.Row="1"
       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
       Canvas.ZIndex="1"
       XYFocusKeyboardNavigation="Enabled">


       <NavigationView
           x:Name="myNavigationView"
           PaneDisplayMode="Top"
           Header="This is Header Text">
           <NavigationView.MenuItems>
               <NavigationViewItem
                   Content="Browse"
                   Tag="SamplePage1"
                   Icon="Library" />
               <NavigationViewItem
                   Content="Track an Order"
                   Tag="SamplePage2"
                   Icon="Map" />
               <NavigationViewItem
                   Content="Order History"
                   Tag="SamplePage3"
                   Icon="Tag" />
           </NavigationView.MenuItems>
       </NavigationView>
   </StackPanel>
</Page>


Could anyone help me how to achieve the bottom menu item?

You code excerpt is incomplete.  Can you please provide the full code?

You can hide the NavigationView built-in Header:
<Grid RowDefinitions="*,Auto,Auto">
    <Frame
        x:Name="ContentFrame"
        Grid.Row="0" />
    <ContentControl
        Grid.Row="1"
        Content="{x:Bind NavigationViewControl.Header, Mode=OneWay}"
        ContentTemplate="{x:Bind NavigationViewControl.HeaderTemplate, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <NavigationView
        x:Name="NavigationViewControl"
        Grid.Row="2"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        AlwaysShowHeader="False"
        Header="HEADER"
        PaneDisplayMode="Top">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Menu #1" />
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Menu #2" />
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Menu #3" />
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
    </NavigationView>
</Grid>


Thanks Andrew. This makes it work.....
